# How to use *ngIf angular 2 to render data in text area or <p> depending on user actions?

Tags: angular

I'm doing a  clickable prototype of a comments widget. Currently I'm showing the comments inside a textarea. I'd like the textarea to be disabled unless the "edit" option is selected and I'd like to show always max 3 rows of the textarea. The issue I'm having with using a textarea and *ngIf as per code below is that if any input was provided for {{note.note}} after clicking "edit" then the input is lost once I click the edit option of another text area. That doesn't happen if I don't use *ngIf but then, without using the ngIf how can I style differently and disable the textarea whether is selected or not? I tried using *ngIf to switch between textarea or paragraph but if I do this I also lost any comments that is typed after clicking "Edit" for another entry.

```html
<div class="note-block">
   <div class="note-author">{{note.name}}</div>
   <div class="time-stamp">{{note.date}}</div> 
   <textarea *ngIf='note!=selectedNote' disabled [ngClass]="{'note-text':true, 'editable':note===selectedNote}">{{note.note}}</textarea>
   <textarea *ngIf='note===selectedNote'[ngClass]="{'note-text':true, 'editable':note===selectedNote}">{{note.note}}</textarea>
   <div class="bottom-notes">
        <ul *ngIf='note!=selectedNote' class="note-actions" >
            <li class="edit" (click)="editableNote(); onSelect(note)">Edit</li>
            <li class="delete" (click)="deleteNote(note); $event.stopPropagation()">Delete</li>
         </ul>
         <ul *ngIf='editNote && note===selectedNote' class="note-actions" >
            <li class="edit">Save</li>
            <li class="delete">Cancel</li>
         </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you want to access the information that the person typed for saving to your back end (or something similar).  If that's the case, then you actually need to capture the data stored in the text area somewhere else besides in the textarea HTML element.

There are a number of ways you can capture the text entered in the text area. The simplest one is to use ngModel and bind your text area to a member variable of your component. That way, when someone types in the text area, it's not lost when ngIf removes the component.

So, import the FormsModule from '@angular/forms' into your NgModule then, add an [(ngModel)]="variable" binding on your text area, where variable is a member variable of your component.

Something like,

```
 <textarea [ngClass]="{'note-text':true, 'editable':note===selectedNote}"
           [disabled]="note!=selectedNote"
           [(ngModel)]="note.note"></textarea>
```

And, as per @Danilo Silveria's suggestion, instead of using two text areas, one disabled, and one not, instead use a binding to the disabled property

Answer (score 2):

you could use only one textarea:

`<textarea *ngIf='note!=selectedNote' [disabled]='!selectedNote' [ngClass]="{'note-text':true, 'editable':note===selectedNote}">{{note.note}}</textarea>`

Comment: This works, though I had to remove the *ngIf in this case to make it work.